# Ruby - Capybara recording test execution videos

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, capybara

I am trying to record and save in a video format my execution tests using Capybara. My tests are passing however I'm getting several errors in my Mac terminal. Also the videos are not being recorded/saved.

**SPEC_HELPER.RB**

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'headless'

headless = Headless.new
headless.start

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
  config.include Capybara::DSL

  config.before(:example) do
    headless.video.start_capture
    page.current_window.resize_to(1200, 800)
  end

  config.after(:example) do |e, scenario|
      name = e.description.gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/, '').tr(' ', '_')
      d = Time.now.strftime("%F-%T")
      page.save_screenshot('log/' + name + '-' + d.to_s + '.png')

      headless.video.stop_and_save('log/' + name + '-' + d.to_s + '.mov')
  end

end

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.default_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
  config.run_server = false
end

Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10
```

**MAC TERMINAL ERROR**

Finished in 19.68 seconds (files took 0.82221 seconds to load)
4 examples, 0 failures

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    8: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capybara-3.14.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:374:in `block in setup_exit_handler'
    7: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capybara-3.14.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:208:in `quit'
    6: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:62:in `quit'
    5: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:81:in `stop'
    4: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:122:in `stop_process'
    3: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/childprocess-0.9.0/lib/childprocess/unix/process.rb:12:in `stop'
    2: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/childprocess-0.9.0/lib/childprocess/unix/process.rb:61:in `send_term'
    1: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/childprocess-0.9.0/lib/childprocess/unix/process.rb:72:in `send_signal'
/Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/childprocess-0.9.0/lib/childprocess/unix/process.rb:72:in `kill': Operation not permitted (Errno::EPERM)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    8: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capybara-3.14.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:374:in `block in setup_exit_handler'
    7: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capybara-3.14.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:208:in `quit'
    6: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:62:in `quit'
    5: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:81:in `stop'
    4: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:122:in `stop_process'
    3: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/childprocess-0.9.0/lib/childprocess/unix/process.rb:12:in `stop'
    2: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/childprocess-0.9.0/lib/childprocess/unix/process.rb:61:in `send_term'
    1: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/childprocess-0.9.0/lib/childprocess/unix/process.rb:72:in `send_signal'
/Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/childprocess-0.9.0/lib/childprocess/unix/process.rb:72:in `kill': Operation not permitted (Errno::EPERM)
    12: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:141:in `block in exit_hook'
    11: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:67:in `block in start'
    10: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:77:in `stop'
     9: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:128:in `stop_server'
     8: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:104:in `connect_to_server'
     7: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:605:in `start'
     6: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:919:in `start'
     5: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:930:in `do_start'
     4: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:945:in `connect'
     3: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
     2: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/timeout.rb:93:in `block in timeout'
     1: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:946:in `block in connect'
/Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:949:in `rescue in block in connect': Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    8: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:141:in `block in exit_hook'
    7: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:67:in `block in start'
    6: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:81:in `stop'
    5: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:81:in `ensure in stop'
    4: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:122:in `stop_process'
    3: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/childprocess-0.9.0/lib/childprocess/unix/process.rb:12:in `stop'
    2: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/childprocess-0.9.0/lib/childprocess/unix/process.rb:61:in `send_term'
    1: from /Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/childprocess-0.9.0/lib/childprocess/unix/process.rb:72:in `send_signal'
/Users/dsanders/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/childprocess-0.9.0/lib/childprocess/unix/process.rb:72:in `kill': Operation not permitted (Errno::EPERM)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing these lines

```
page.save_screenshot('log/' + name + '-' + d.to_s + '.png')
headless.video.stop_and_save('log/' + name + '-' + d.to_s + '.mov')
```

With

```
#please note for this ../ from this file to root just reach to root of the project. in my case root 

root_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../")

page.save_screenshot(File.join(root_path,'log/' + name + '-' + d.to_s + '.png'))
headless.video.stop_and_save(File.join(root_path,'log/' + name + '-' + d.to_s + '.mov'))
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately did not work. The following error is being printed now:         
"uninitialized constant Rails"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you are not using rails. I am going to update the answer now.

Comment: hi did not work :( .. now the original error is happening again, displaying the terminal errors and the videos are not being created/saved..

Comment: HI, sorry, it's really strange. Can you somehow share me your setup may be share project on git, I will be happy to assist.

Comment: Nice, I did some changes and back to my original file (original error).. follow my github path.. thanks helping me :) . - https://github.com/dsanders23/ruby_git/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb

Comment: how you run rspec ?

Comment: Actually, sometimes I use the command "rspec --tag @check -fd", whe check means a specific scenario..

Comment: Hi @Nitesh, my comment above made sense to you? :) thanks!

Comment: Hey all, I'm still do not have an answer for it.. someone can help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

my searching show that Mac is not compatible with Xvfb which is something that Headless uses. Even if you get pass the rails error, you might not pass this one.